When can you use the $SEID$ subsystem to study the dynamics of the $SEIHDR$ epidemic model?
I am working on the following model:
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{split}
 \frac{dS}{dt} &=  \Pi- \left( \lambda   + \nu + \mu \right) S\\
    \frac{dE}{dt}  &=  \lambda  S - \left( \alpha + \tau + \mu \right) E \\
    \frac{dI}{dt}  &=  \alpha  E - \left( \gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r  + \mu \right) I\\
    \frac{dH}{dt}  &=  \tau E + \gamma_h  I - \left(  \eta_r + \eta_b  + \mu \right) H\\    
        \frac{dD}{dt}  &=  \gamma_d I - b D\\    
    \frac{dR}{dt} &= \nu S + \gamma_r I + \eta_r H - \mu R
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
where $$ \lambda = \frac{\beta (I+\delta D) }{N},$$
with the initial conditions:
$S(0)  = S_0,$ $E(0) = E_0,$ $I(0) = I_0, H(0) = H_0, D(0) = D_0$ and $R(0) = R_0.$
To make the theoretical analysis of the above system more tractable, I transform the system using proportionate variables $s = \frac{S}{N}, e = \frac{E}{N}, i = \frac{I}{N}, d = \frac{D}{N}$ and $r= \frac{R}{N}.$ The transformed equations become:
\begin{equation} \label{eq01n1}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}(s) &=  \frac{\Pi}{N} -s (\nu + \beta (i+\delta d) + \mu)  - s  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h \right), \\
\frac{d}{dt}(e) &=  \beta (i+\delta d)s -e (\alpha + \tau + \mu)  - e  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h  \right) ,\\
\frac{d}{dt}(i) &= \alpha e - i ( \gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r  + \mu) - i  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h  \right),\\
\frac{d}{dt}(h) &= \tau e + \gamma_h i - h (\eta_r + \eta_b + \mu) - h  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h  \right), \\
\frac{d}{dt}(d) &=   \gamma_d i - bd - d  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h   \right),\\
\frac{d}{dt}(r) &= \nu s + \gamma_r i + \eta_r h - \mu r - r  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h   \right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The transformed system has the disease-free equilibrium (DFE) $$P_0 = \left(s_0^* , 0 , 0, 0, 0, r_0^* \right)$$ where
$s_0^* = \frac{\mu}{ \nu + \mu},$ $r_0^* = \frac{\nu}{\mu(\nu + \mu)}$ and the endemic equilibrium (EE) $$P^* = \left(s^* , e^* , i^*, h^*, d^*, r^* \right)$$ where
$s^* = \frac{b(\gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r + \mu)(\alpha + \tau + \mu)}{\alpha \beta \left(b+\delta \gamma_d \right)}, i^* = \frac{ \mu \left( \mathcal{R}_c - 1 \right) }{ \mathcal{R}_c \left[ ( \gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r   ) ( 1 + \frac{ \tau +\mu}{\alpha}) + \gamma_d \left( \frac{\tau+\mu}{\alpha} + \mu \right) \right] },$ $e^* = \frac{i^* ( \gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r  + \mu)}{\alpha}, h^* = \frac{\tau e^* + \gamma_h i^*}{\eta_r + \eta_b + \mu},  d^* = \frac{\gamma_d i^*}{b}$
$r^* = \frac{1}{\mu} \left(  \nu s^* +  \gamma_r i^* + \eta_r h^*  \right),$ and $\mathcal{R}_c = \frac{\alpha \mu \beta \left(b+\delta \gamma_d \right)}{b(\gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r  + \mu)(\alpha + \tau + \mu)(\nu + \mu)}.$
I want to study the local stability of the transformed system at the DFE and EE. As you can see, the dynamics of the transformed system are completely determined by the variables (s, e, i,) and (d) since (h) and (r) can be understood using the other variables. Thus, can I focus on the following subsystem for local stability instead of the whole transformed system?
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}(s) &=  \frac{\Pi}{N} -s (\nu + \beta (i+\delta d) + \mu)  - s  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h \right), \\
\frac{d}{dt}(e) &=  \beta (i+\delta d)s -e (\alpha + \tau + \mu)  - e  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h  \right) ,\\
\frac{d}{dt}(i) &= \alpha e - i ( \gamma_h + \gamma_d + \gamma_r  + \mu) - i  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h  \right),\\
\frac{d}{dt}(d) &=   \gamma_d i - bd - d  \left(  \frac{\Pi}{N} - \mu + (\mu - b)d - \eta_b h   \right),\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
